# Install and use Azure SDK

Tags: composer

Is it possible to install Azure SDK via Composer within a Drupal site and use it in custom modules?

```
{
  "require": {
    "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
  }
}
```

Also according to Microsoft docs, below code should be used in order to use Azure API. Not sure where though.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
```

Comment: The autoload file is already included so you don't need the first line, other than that you've got it, that's how you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to autoload it in Drupal.

what you need is in the root of the Drupal run :

```
composer require microsoft/windowsazure
```

then in your custom module use it with

`use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;`